# Make pdf.js 1.5 and require.js play nice together

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pdf.js

In my project I have long used require.js together with the pdf.js library. Pdf.js have until recently been putting itself on the global object. I could still use it in my requirejs config by using a shim. The pdfjs library will in turn load another library called pdf.worker. In order to find this module the solution was to add a property to the global PDFJS object called workerSrc and point to the file on disk. This could be done before or after loading the pdfjs library.
The pdfjs library uses the pdf.worker to start a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) and to do so it needs the path to a source file.

When I tried to update the pdfjs library in my project to a new version (1.5.314) the way to load and include the library have changed to use UMD modules and now everything get's a bit tricky.

The pdfjs library checks if the environment is using requirejs and so it defines itself as a module named "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf". When this module loads it checks for a module named "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker". Since I have another folder structure I have added them to my requirejs config object with a new path:

```
paths: {
    "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf": "vendor/pdfjs/build/pdf",
    "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker": "vendor/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker"
}
```

This is to make the module loader to find the modules at all. In development this works great. When I try to use the requirejs optimizer in my grunt build step however, it will put all of my project files into one single file. This step will try to include the pdf.worker module as well and this generates an error:

> Error: Cannot uglify2 file: vendor/pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js. Skipping
>   it. Error is: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Since the worker source needs to be in a single file on disk I don't want this module to be included.
So I've tried two different config-settings in the requirejs config.
The first attempt was to override the paths property in my grunt build options:

```
paths: {
    "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker": "empty:"
}
```

The second thing to test is to exclude it from my module:

```
modules: [{
    name: "core/app",
    exclude: [
        "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker"
    ]
}]
```

Both techniques should tell the optimizer not to include the module but both attempts ended up with the same error as before. The requirejs optimizer still tries to include the module into the build and the attempt to uglify it ends up with a RangeError.

One could argue that since the uglify step fails it will not be included and I can go about my bussiness, but if the uglify step should happen to start working at a new update of pdfjs - what then?

Can anyone help me figure out why the requirejs config won't just exclude it in the build step and how to make it do so.

Comment: See if https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/webpack or https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/browserify will make it clearer or help -- not all bundlers play well with pdf.js. uglify error is different one (see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7044) and requires workaround to make it work on chrome.

Comment: The uglify error I experience isn't during runtime which seems to be the case in the bug you referred to. My problems occurs in the build step with r.js. The problem I have is that the optimizer still tries to pick up the worker file when I tell it not to.

Comment: Right, webpack and browserify are using package.json to ignore it. There was [issue(s)](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/search?q=Maximum+call+stack+size+exceeded&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) with uglify related to "Maximum call stack size exceeded" -- I was there was some configuration workaround proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the core of my problem was and now I have a way to solve the problem and make my build process to work. My build step in grunt is using [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) and I needed to override some options in the config for this job.

1. I didn't want the pdf.worker module to be included in my concatenated and minified production code.
2. I didn't want r.js to minify it only to later exclude it from the concatenated file.

I tried to solve the first problem thinking that it would mean that the second problem also should be solved. When I figured out the two were separate I finally found a solution.

In the [r.js example](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) on github there is a property named [fileExclusionRegExp](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L494). This is what I now use to tell r.js not to copy the file over to the build folder.

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /pdf.worker.js/
```

Second, I need to tell the optimizer to not include this module in the concatenated file. This is done by overriding the paths property for this module to the value of ["empty:"](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L40).

```
paths: {
  "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker": "empty:"
}
```

Now my grunt build step will work without errors and all is well.
Thanks to [async5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765767/async5) for informing me about the bug with uglify and the pdf.worker. The workaround is applied in another grunt task that uglify the worker and copies it into the build-folder separately. The options object for the [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) task will need this property in order to not break the pdf.worker file:

```
compress: {
  sequences: false
}
```

Now my project works great when built for production.